# How access variables within method block?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to access a method block but I have no idea how to:

```
__block NSString *username;
PFUser *user = [[self.messageData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"author"];
[user fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
    username = [object objectForKey:@"username"]; 
    NSLog(@"%@", username); //returns "bob";
}];
NSLog(@"%@", username); //returns null
```

How do I access the variable 'username' from this code outside of the block?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually you are accessing the variable username outside the block. You are getting null because the block runs in another thread and you set the value after the block finish it's execution. So, your last line has been already executed in main thread while the block was running , so it's value was not set when last line was executed.That's why you are getting null.

Comment: this is a great answer! but unfortunately im running my code in tableview:cellforrowatindexpath. I'm querying as the cells are being assigned, which makes it difficult to wait for the block to issue a function call. any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

`fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock` is an asynchronous method. That's why your last `NSLog` returns `null` because this it is performed before `username` was retrieved. So what you want is probably to call some method inside the block to be sure that it executes after you fetched your user data. Something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    MyUserCell *userCell = (MyUserCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyUserCellIdentifier];
    PFUser *user = [[self.messageData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"author"];
    userCell.user = user;
    [user fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
        if (object == userCell.user && !error) {
            username = [object objectForKey:@"username"]; 
            cell.textLabel.text = userName;
        }
    }]; 
}
```

UPDATE: The answer is updated to for the case when the block is called inside `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method as requested. 
NOTE: Here you will probably need a custom cell to store a reference to the current user, because if you are reusing your cells the block callback might be called after the same cell was reused for a different indexPath (so it will have a different user).

Comment: this is a great answer! but unfortunately im running my code in tableview:cellforrowatindexpath. I'm querying as the cells are being assigned, which makes it difficult to wait for the block to issue a function call. any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using NSOperationQueue as presented in WWDC. See this article for reference, it think it would be helpful:
https://stavash.wordpress.com/2012/12/14/advanced-issues-asynchronous-uitableviewcell-content-loading-done-right/

Answer (score -2):

Below is the example of what I do: try it:

Write this below import statement

```
typedef double (^add_block)(double,double);
```

Block - Write this in view did load

```
__block int bx=5;
[self exampleMethodWithBlockType:^(double a,double b){
    int ax=2;
    //bx=3;
    bx=1000;
    NSLog(@"AX = %d && BX = %d",ax,bx);
    return a+b; 
}];

NSLog(@"BX = %d",bx);
```

Method:

```
-(void)exampleMethodWithBlockType:(add_block)addFunction {
    NSLog(@"Value using block type = %0.2f",addFunction(12.4,7.8));
}
```

Comment: can u pls execute this code  __block NSString *username;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.0 animations:^{
          username= @"hI";
         NSLog(@"%@", username);
    }];
        NSLog(@"%@", username);

Comment: It runs perfectly. Then I think the problem is what Ayon is saying

Comment: This answers nothing, as this uses a synchronous block execution.